# Using arrays and inverting their sums

Tags: c, arrays, windows, sum

I'd like for the sums to be a[0] + b[3], a[1] + b[2] and so on (up to a[3] and b[0]), yet I cannot seem to get my code to work. Below is the code that does a[0] + b[0]. Any ideas on how I would change my code in order to get my desired output? I tried changing the i's in the sums

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <math.h>

#define SIZE 4

int main()

{

    int i;

    int sum[SIZE];

    int a[SIZE] = { 2, 3, 5, 8 };

    int b[SIZE] = { 1, 0, 4, 6 };


for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)

{

    printf("Enter a[%d] \n", i);

    scanf_s("%d", &a[i]);

}

for (i = 3; i < SIZE; --i)

{
    printf("Enter b[%d] \n", i);

    scanf_s("%d", &b[i]);

    {
        if (i == 0)
            break;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)

{

    printf("c[%d] = %d and d[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i], i, b[i]);

}

    sum[SIZE] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)

    {
        sum[i] = a[i] + b[i];  //I tried writing individual statements for each by using sum [0] = a[3] + b[0] etc. but that didn't work
    }


for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)

{

    printf ("sum[%d] = %d \n", i, sum[i]); // I also tried altering the print statement but that didn't work which is why I resorted back to this original code

}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Could you please re-post this without the line breaks? Seems like some sort of copy/paste issue. And while you are at it, please fix the indention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
         sum[i] = a[i] + b[SIZE - i - 1];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two indices. Increment one while decrementing the other in the loop.

```
int ai = 0;
int bi = SIZE-1;

for ( ; ai < SIZE && bi >= 0; ++ai, --bi )
{
   sum[ai] = a[ai] + b[bi];
}
```

Comment: @Jurion, I misunderstood the indices at first.

Comment: You still should put int bi = SIZE - 1;

Comment: @Jurion, makes sense.